# How so show SSH key in git log?

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

We are using git with gitolite and sometimes my users change there names with

```
git config --global user.name
```

so I would like to see some more details in the log to find out if someone has change the name setting but is still the same workstation (ssh key).  Anyway to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent someone who is attempting to trick `git` into thinking they are someone else when committing?

Comment: no I am trying to track someone of my programmers that maybe doing that... I what to see what workstation ready checkin the work

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the ssh keys in commit messages will be a complete overkill. You don't want your commit messages to look up completely screwed some x days later, just because each of them contain different ssh keys.

You should have a look at [git notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) to supplement your commits with additonal information. In the notes, you can add the committer's Username and other environment variables.

Worst case, you can add the ssh keys in git notes, though I am not sure how that stops malicious users who currently fake commits in some other user's name from trying to hack around and get hold of some other user's ssh keys. 
More importantly, if developers are doing this in complicity with each other, the ssh keys will be completely insufficient.

Assuming you are on linux, you can get the username using

```
printenv | grep USER
```

You can similarly choose other details you need from the environment that you need to put into the git note.

Next, you can write a post-commit [hook](http://githooks.com/) which automatically adds all this information post every commit.

Comment: i dont see how git notes will help at all

Comment: The question poster is asking about people that are dishonestly trying to trick git into believing they are someone else.  Using an SSH based on their machine could maybe deal with that.  Is it possible to have that information automatically added to the commits?

Comment: yes... I am trying to see if the log can show ssh key information

Comment: @JMSAZ2013 the git notes are handy so that such irrelevant details (as ssh keys for normal users) do not mess up the commit messages. Imagine doing a git log one day to find all your commit messages screwed around having loooong ssh keys in the commit messages

Comment: @BlackVegetable If the question is of trust, I have no idea where the lack of it stops. You mean to say, one smartass developer, who can fake commit in some other user's name, won't try to hack around and get hold of the other user's ssh keys? More importantly, if developers are doing this in complicity with each other, will the ssh keys be enough to stop them?

Comment: @ansh0l I agree with you.  On another note, try re-reading your last comment as though it were the trailer for a new movie coming out next Summer.  Hilarity ensues.

Comment: so no way from logs to find the workstation that pushed the code

Comment: @JMSAZ2013 If you are talking of commits that have already been pushed, there is no way AFAIK. My suggestions are for any future commits. You need to clarify in your question that you are looking for that information for old commits.

Comment: how can I really track the commits down to the same workstation/user

Answer (score 1):

In the gitolite 3.x you can IIRC add a VREF constraint that committer (or author) matches SSH key used, or HTTP auth user (I guess it uses the username part of `user.email`, or whole of `user.email`).

Though this is *discouraged* as a pre-receive hook (i.e. block), you can set up post-receive hook instead to log and compare committers with auth usernames.

Comment: If the user is smartly faking the `user.name`, can't he fake the `user.email` next?

Comment: yes.. anyway from log to see workstation or ssh key that did the push

Comment: @ansh0l: well, the proposed usage of mentioned gitolite3 check is to catch mistakes, not malicious behavior.  Anyway, user can fake `user.email`, but not SSH key / HTTP auth used to push.